# Why are "Release" and "Freed" used for the first generation wife images?

Tags: agarest-war-zero

After you marry your chosen girl (or choose one but have the other two fully in love with you apparently), you're given a movie called "[WIFE] Release" and an image based on that move called "[WIFE] Freed" (maybe the other way around) with "[WIFE]" being Linda, Routier, or Sayane.

Now, I don't really understand why they use the wording because:

> Linda, Routier and Sayane die with Sieg at the end of the First Generation.

I'm wondering: Is this because of a bad translation from Japanese, or is there some innuendo in which "freed" and "release" may mean "to conceive a child" considering what the images and movie actually represent?

*NOTE: I know this is a game, but I have learned that questions to some games, particular ones which are like a visual novel, tend to get answers here rather than on Arqade if they're not directly related to gameplay (such as questions about the story).*

UPDATE:
I've been playing *Agarest: Generations of War*; in *Zero*, I got the marriage and a "Sealed" image from an event of the heroines from the first generation of *Agarest: Generation of War*. I thought that how they used "Sealed" was in the same way as "Release" and "Freed"; however, it does make sense to use "Sealed" in *Agarest: Generations of War*.

> The First Generation Heroines (and most likely other generations but the last) are sealed up with their husband in the Pillar.

However, while it makes sense to use "Sealed" in *Agarest: Generations of War*, it still doesn't make sense to use "Release" and "Freed" in *Agarest: Generations of War Zero* 'cause they aren't freed or released.

> Of course, while Linda, Routier, Sayane, and Sieg return when you enter the Boundary Plane, you can only get to the Boundary Plane if you get the True Ending and they are still dead.

Comment: For reference, our current policy, based on [this meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/415/24), is that anime-style games, including visual novels, are allowed so long as you stick to plot questions. Gameplay questions are not allowed. I'm pretty sure this qualifies both as anime-style and plot-related.

Comment: I think you accidentally a few words at the end, there. "[Be]cause they aren't..."

Comment: @Eric it might be because of how i speak, "[Be]cause they aren't" relates to just what i had just said prior to that thus avoiding having to repeat myself

Comment: @Memor-X Yes, that is typical in English; however, I couldn't figure out exactly what you were referring to in your previous statements. It makes much more sense now, thanks.